# setLabel after page change jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I would like to change column names after gridComplete, so I call in gridComplete block :

```
setTimeout(function(){
            formatCols()
        },"200");
```

The formatCols function is a ajax function :

```
function formatCols(){
var ids = new Array();
$("tr.jqgrow").each(function(){
    ids.push($(this).attr("id"));
})
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data:{
        podszkola: $('#szkola_select').val(),
        ids: ids
    },
    url: location.protocol+"//"+location.host+"/sekretariat/ksiegaewidencji/getyears",
    success: function(data){
        var columnNames = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
        for(var i =1; i<=13 ; i++){
            $("#list").setLabel(columnNames[i+1].name.toString(), data.response[i] ,"",{});
        }

        if(firstGrid){
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
                useColSpanStyle: true, 
                groupHeaders:[
                {
                    startColumnName: 'Nr.', 
                    numberOfColumns: 2, 
                    titleText: '<em>Dane Osobowe</em>'
                },
                {
                    startColumnName: 'r1', 
                    numberOfColumns: 13, 
                    titleText: '<em>Spełnienie obowiązku szkolnego w kolejnych latach</em>'
                }
                ]
            });
        }
        firstGrid = false;
        updateCellWidth("list")
        $("#mainLoadingScreen").hide();
    }
})
```

}

The main part of these function is :

```
for(var i =1; i<=13 ; i++){
            $("#list").setLabel(columnNames[i+1].name.toString(), data.response[i] ,"",{});
        }
```

It work's fine, but only once ! When I try to change page of grid table function change the names of wrong columns. I think the problem is first argument of setLabel() function, but I don't know what should I pass there to make it work correctly. How to get current (after change) colNames, or simply how to make it work ?

Thanks in advance.